# How to get the digits of a number (in a int variable) using a char pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, digits

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Function that separate the digits of the number (i don't know how to do it, please help me)

```
    void separateDigits(int number, char *digits) {
        }
```

This code print the digits separated

```
        int main(void) {
          int number;
          char digits[10];
          printf("Type one number: ");
          scanf("%d", &num);
          separateDigits(num, digits);
          for (int i = 0; digits[i]; i++)
            printf("digit[%d] = %c\n", i, digits[i]);
          return 0;
        }
```

Input:
80

Output:
digit[0]=8,
digit[1]=0

Comment: To get the individual digits, divide by 10.  `12345 % 10` is `5`, `12345 / 10` is `1234`, and then `1234 % 10` is `4`.

Comment: Alternatively, `sprintf(digits, "%d", num)`, and then your digits are `digits[0]`, `digits[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse(char *str) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
    }
}
void separateDigits(int number, char *digits) {

    int i = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        digits[i] = number % 10 + '0';
        number /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    digits[i] = '\0';
    reverse(digits);
}
int main(void) {
          int num;
          char digits[10];
          printf("Type one number: ");
          scanf("%d", &num);
          separateDigits(num, digits);
          for (int i = 0; digits[i]; i++)
            printf("digit[%d] = %c\n", i, digits[i]);
          return 0;
}
```